# Excluding directories in Exuberant CTags

Tags: exuberant-ctags

I'm working with a very large code base and I find it useful to be selective about which directories are included for use with Exuberant Ctags.

The `--exclude` option works well to eliminate individual file and directory names (with globing wildcards), but I can't figure out how to get it to exclude path patterns containing more than one directory.

For example, I may want to exclude a directory `tests`, but only when processing `thirdparty\tests` (under Windows).  The problem is if I just use `--exclude=tests` I exclude too many directories, including a test directory in the code I'm actively working on.

Here are some things I've tried:

```
--exclude=thirdparty\tests
--exclude=thirdparty\\tests
--exclude=*\thirdparty\tests
--exclude=*\\thirdparty\\tests
--exclude=thirdparty/tests
```

Ctags silently ignores all these as evidenced by an examination of the tags file.

How can I exclude a directory only when it is preceded by a given parent directory?

ADDED:

Here's my `ctags --version` output:

```
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Jul  9 2009, 17:05:35
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +win32, +regex, +internal-sort
```

Comment: Does `ctags --version` show `+wildcards` in the output?

Comment: @sarnold: Hmmm, nope!  So you think one of the `*\thirdparty\tests` would work if I had that option?

Comment: Yeah, it probably would -- but I wouldn't know how to go about getting the wildcards support under Windows. (Having a `/bin/sh` installed when compiling it might be sufficient.)

Comment: I had originally answered you question as if you only wanted to exluded a few directories. I think your best be it to use --exclude option to use a file with the names of the directories you want to exlude. its in the manual I think all you need to do is put an @ in front of the filename

Comment: @Will: Thanks, this was a while ago, but I think I wrote a Python script to filter exactly as I needed, wrote that to a file, and used @ as you alluded.

Comment: The manual also notes that you should quote wildcards when they are supported (otherwise the shell expands them).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude multiple directories with Exuberant ctags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819649/how-to-exclude-multiple-directories-with-exuberant-ctags)

Comment: @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功, note that this question was asked first.  The other question is the duplicate.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey hi Codie, Current consensus is to close by "quality": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newb Google keywords on the title.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At some point it might be easier to define the list of files you do want indexed; save that list to a file, and use `ctags -L <filename>` to index just the chosen few.

This lets you use `find(1)` to prune the directories you don't want to index, e.g.:

```
find . -path ./Documentation -prune -o -print > indexme
```

would skip all the files in all subdirectories of `./Documentation`.

Comment: You'll have to get a version of `find` for Windows though.

Comment: Or scrap together something Good Enough if `find(1)` is too hard to port. You really just need a list of file names, not the full functionality of `find(1)`.

Comment: +1 that's a good suggestion, I can use a tool to generate a list of directories I want, which will give me more filtering options beyond the ones I asked for.  Today, I'm too lazy.  :-)

Comment: Lazy is good; it makes you look for new ways to solve problems. :)

Comment: Could someone do a noob step-by-step of this process? Tnx

Comment: @JoseBrowne: I think the consensus is to use a two-step process: first run a tool to build a file for ctags to consume, then run ctags and reference that file.  The choice of tools is up to you.  If you generate a list of files to include, you can use  the -L option as Sarnold suggested, or if you generate a list of options--notably --exclude options--you can use ctags @<file> to read this options as if you had typed them all at the command line.

Comment: I prefer `find . -type f -not -path './Documentation/*'` because it's more intuitive and less obscure

Answer (score 10):

```
ack -f | ctags -L -
```

[`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/) will list the source files in a given dir. You can limit the scope to a specific language with `ack -f --ruby` or `ack -f --type=ruby`. You can exclude dirs as well with `--ignore-dir`.

Use `ack --dump` to see the built-in file types for ack.

Comment: That rocks.  This never occurred to me.

Comment: Great answer.  I used `git ls-files | ctags -L -`

Answer (score 0):

ctags -R --exclude="thirdparty/test/**"

use "dir/**" fix my case