# Why ctags exclusion (--exclude) doesn't work for me?

Tags: vim, tags, ide, ctags

I'm just trying to figure out why does the following command not work:

```
ctags -R ../.. --exclude={build_kernel,build_user}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ctags` doesn't even apply the `--exclude` block. Just try:

```
ctags -R --exclude={build_kernel,build_user} ../..
```

Also read: [How to exclude multiple directories with Exuberant ctags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819649/how-to-exclude-multiple-directories-with-exuberant-ctags)