# ctags in sublime text

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, sublimetext, ctags

I've just download [sublime text 2 beta 2182](http://www.sublimetext.com/) under ubuntu 10.10 with Exuberant Ctags 5.8

I want to use it for c++ coding and I need some auto completition and code navigation. (I was used to eclipse with cdt)

I googled and I found ctags a cool tool that can do it, and there is a plugin support for sublime text [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags).

The problem is that I want create tag file from:

1. c++ standard lib (`std::vector` `std::map etc`)
2. all classes of the framework i'm using.

Point 1 is (i think) the same of point 2, I just only have to create a tag list of std lib in my `/usr/include/c++/4.4.5/`

so I've downloaded the plugin and installed it, I made a taglist in this way:

```
$ cd /absolute_path_of_my_cpp_framework/
$ ctags -R *
```

I modified `/home/me/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/CTagss/CTags.sublime-settings` with this line:

```
"extra_tag_files" : [".gemtags", "/absolute_path_of_my_cpp_framework/tags"]
```

Now I open a cpp file, point the cursor on a class name of my framework and used the key binding `ctrl+t ctrl+t` and nothing happened. Only this message in the bar in the bottom:

> can't find "class_name"

Can someone help me?

Comment: StackOverflow is more a site for programming questions, not questions about programs for programming. You might want to try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: i posted it here because here in stackoverflow there are 99 question about ctags in superuser only 14. by the way, i just posted it in superuser

Comment: try `"extra_tag_paths" : ["/absolute_path_of_my_cpp_framework/tags"]`

Comment: Why not post this in the sublime forums? This does sound just like a question for that place...

Comment: open up the sublimetext console and invoke the plugin and you'll see any possible errors that might have occurred.

Comment: Hm, not sure about ctags, but have you tried https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang?

Comment: clang uses llvm machine and i don't need it, and it does not fit very well with some project i have to deal with

Answer (score 7):

I don't personally use Sublime Text, but assuming it uses tag files in a similar manner to vim, you need to generate additional info for C++ completion.

Use ctags with the following options:

`ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++`

Info was taken from [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion), which also supplies copies of the standard library headers that you can use to generate tags.

Answer (score 2):

### Shell Commands:

`$ cd /absolute_path_of_my_cpp_framework/` (1)

`$ ctags -R --languages=c++ --langmap=c++:+.inl --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --totals=yes --verbose=yes` (2)

`$ ctags -a -R --languages=c++ /usr/include/c++/4.4.5/ --fields=+iaS --extra=+q  --totals=yes --verbose=yes` (3)

`$ subl .` (4)

### Description:

(1) Go to the root folder of your project to ensure that the tags file will be created there.

(2) Generate a new tags file for all C++ files in your project, adding support for .inl files, inheritance, access modifiers, class-qualified scoping etc.

(3) Append tags for the C++ standard lib headers to your generated tags file.

(4) Open the folder in Sublime Text.

### References:

1. http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html
2. https://www.chromium.org/developers/sublime-text
3. http://www.tarosys.com/2014/07/adding-another-file-type-for-ctags.html
4. [Exuberant ctags exclude directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819649/exuberant-ctags-exclude-directories)
5. [Vim and Ctags: Ignoring certain files while generating tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736656/vim-and-ctags-ignoring-certain-files-while-generating-tags)
6. https://www.topbug.net/blog/2012/03/17/generate-ctags-files-for-c-slash-c-plus-plus-source-files-and-all-of-their-included-header-files/